# UnassignedReferenceException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the error

> UnassignedReferenceException:

even after assigning it in the Editor?

I think the following screenshot provides everything needed.

The screenshot below shows that the `muzzleFlash` variable has something assigned to it but it still causing error.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
public class GUN : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float dmg =10;
    public float range=100;
    public Camera fpscam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;

    void Update () 
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            shoot ();
        }
    }   

    void shoot ()
    {   
        muzzleFlash.Play ();
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (fpscam.transform.position, fpscam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
                Debug.Log (hit.transform.name);
                Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target> ();

                if (target != null) 
                {
                    target.takedmg (dmg);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your gun script

Comment: using UnityEngine;
public class GUN : MonoBehaviour {
 public float dmg =10;
 public float range=100;
 public Camera fpscam;
 public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;

 void Update () {

  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
  {
  shoot ();
  }
 } 
  
 void shoot ()
 {   muzzleFlash.Play ();
  RaycastHit hit;
  if (Physics.Raycast (fpscam.transform.position, fpscam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
  
   {
   Debug.Log (hit.transform.name);
   Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target> ();
   if (target != null) {


   target.takedmg (dmg);  }
}
}
}

Comment: Edit your question and add it there as a code.

Comment: done i guess ...

Comment: Ok. Can you upload another screenshot while the game is running? I want to see if something changes. By the way, are you destroying the `muzzleFlash` from code? Maybe calling the `Destroy` function?

Comment: there is no Destroy function ..i had one but i removed it from the code

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ABnIk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that the something is assigned to the `muzzleFlash` variable.

It is very likely that you have mistakenly attached the Gun script to another GameObject. When you did this, that instance of script does not have anything assigned to its `muzzleFlash` variable. Find where the `Gun` is attached to and remove it.

To do that, select the `Gun` script from the Project tab then Go to *Assets* ---> *Find References In Scene*. Remove the `Gun` script from other GameObjects.

[image]